# Export Linux native filesystem to Windows over USB as VFAT or NTFS

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, usb, emulation

How can I present a Linux native file system, e.g. YAFFS2, ext3, to Windows over USB such that it appears as VFAT or NTFS?
I currently share a VFAT loop back file using the g_file_storage kernel module. Ideally, there is some translation layer available that presents one file system as another type of file system.

Comment: Which hardware are you using? i.e. what is the client device?

Comment: This sounds like you are developing something similar to a cell phone, that is hooked up to a PC using USB. You want your cell phone to appear as a USB mass storage device.
Right?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I use Ext2Fsd to show ext3 and ext4 file systems in Windows, but I am not sure how it will behave with loop back files. Try it at http://www.ext2fsd.com.
I however never tried it with YAFFS2, but it is definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The program [vsFat - Virtual Synthetic filesystem(github)](https://github.com/SeanMollet/vsFat) appears to do, what you are (maybe still) attempting to do. Or some other reader.

> This program generates a synthetic FAT32 filesystem given a directory on the local system. The primary purpose of such an arrangement is to export the FS via Linux usb gadgets to a physical device that is incapable of connecting to a network drive.
>
> This FS is read-only, limited to 2TB of total size and 4GB maximum file sizes, as per the FAT32 specification.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41) is a description, how to expose this virtual block device via USB. It's geared to a Raspberry PI0w, but the instructions will works on any device, that has something in `/sys/class/udc/` after `modprobe libcomposite`. "UDC" -> "USB DualRole Controller"